# PageViewController dynamic initialisation in Swift?

Tags: swift

How we can convert this in swift for dynamic page view controller initialization?
where `pageController` is a property.

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

Comment: you should also attempt to show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Just like this?

```
self.pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
```